# How to post table rows data to a controller w/o using ajax in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, controller

What is want to achieve is I have a form to adds rows with data to a html table, it's like a temporary table and all the data from it will be added in just one submit button. How can I possibly do this?

This is my sample table structure, data from it must be added to db

```
<form asp-action="Create">
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!--some other fields-->
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Check #</th>
                <th>Check Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <!--some other fields-->
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="Amount" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Amount" class="text-danger"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="Check_No" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Check_No" class="text-danger"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="Check_Date" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Check_Date" class="text-danger"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!--row 2-->
            <!--row 3-->
            <!--row 4-->
            <!--etc..-->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
```

And here is my controller code so far, i don't know what do I need to change

```
// POST: Books/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Year,Month,Document_Code,GLA_Code,Expense_Code,Function_Code,Document_Reference_No,Document_Date,Quantity,Amount,Check_No,Check_Date,Remarks,Encoder")] Book book)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(book);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(book);
    }
```

What must needed to be change in my view and controller, and help will is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here.

First, if you've got a table of "books" (plural), the input names need to be indexed. You then also need to accept something like `List<Book>` instead of `Book` as the param to your action method. It's a little hard to tell with just the code provided, but I'd imagine you're repeating these inputs, all with the same names for each row. If that's the case, only the values for the last item will be posted. Making it a list of items enables you to post them all.

Simplistically, that means your inputs need to have names like `[0].Amount`, which Razor will generate for you if you use a `for` loop and render the inputs like:

```
<input asp-for="@Model[i].Amount" class="form-control" />
```

If you're adding the additional rows (and contained inputs) via JavaScript, you'll need to ensure that you're generating these indexed names properly yourself. A JS templating library may help in this regard.

Second, *do not use `Bind`*. Just don't. It's awful, horrible, and kills both puppies and kittens. For more explanation see my post, [Bind is Evil](https://cpratt.co/bind-is-evil/). Use a view model instead. As a general rule you should *never* post an entity class. Your entity classes serve the database and its concerns, which are almost always different from the concerns of the view. Additionally, you should *never* just blindly save something posted by a user. Even if you insist on using your entity class to bind to, you can improve the security and safety of your code exponentially by literally mapping the values from the posted version of the class over to a new instance you create. Then, you know *exactly* what is being persisted to the database (without the godforsaken `Bind`) and you also have the opportunity to sanitize input as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem, but using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and Razor Pages. I was looking for a way to add and remove rows from a table with JavaScript, and then post it. My problem was to post the table without Ajax. Based in the question and in the accepted answer, I could do that.

Here is **Index.cshtml.cs**:

```
public class IndexViewModel {

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<ResourceViewModel> Resources { get; set; }

}

public class ResourceViewModel {

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

}

public class IndexModel: PageModel {

    [BindProperty]
    public IndexViewModel ViewModel {get; set; }

    public void OnGet() {
        // You can fill your ViewModel property here.
    }

    public void OnPost() {
        // You can read your posted ViewModel property here.
    }

}
```

Here is **Index.cshtml**:

```
@page
@model IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ViewModel.Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="ViewModel.Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>Key</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for(int i = 0; i < Model.ViewModel.Resources.Count; i++) {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="ViewModel.Resources[i].Key" type="hidden" />
                            @Model.ViewModel.Resources[i].Key
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="ViewModel.Resources[i].Value" type="hidden" />
                            @Model.ViewModel.Resources[i].Value
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

Notice I've used `type="hidden"` because I didn't want the user to edit the table directly.
I hope you find this useful!